# Can anybody check is my English email ok?

Tags: grammaticality

I'm learning English as a foreign language, I'm preparing for a school exams, so I wrote a simple email which goal was informing friends and family about the party which I'm doing because my sister got engaged. I will really appreciate if you can help and show me some mistakes or better ways to do something. If it is not a good place for questions like this one, please tell me about some website where somebody could check my emails.

Email content:

*Hi everyone!
My sister got engaged with her boyfriend. We are making a little party to celebrate it. It will take place in our home on 22th May at 4pm. We will dance and sign, there will be also some snacks. I didn't invited many people, so it will be a comfortable afternoon spent in a small group of people. Please let me know will you be able to arrived. Waiting for your email.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really good! I have some really small edits, just grammar and spelling. 1. People get engaged *to* each other, not with. 2. Generally people say they are *throwing* or *having* a party, not making one. 3. *22nd*, not 22th. 4. You misspelled *sing*. 5. There will *also be*, not be also. 6. You didn't *invite* many people, not invited. You also want to know when people will *arrive*, not *arrived*. Finally, 7. Generally you would say that the afternoon will be spent *with* a small group, not in.

Overall this was very clear and easy to read though, I had no trouble understanding what you were saying so good job! Let me know if you would like me to explain any of the corrections.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I would be grateful if you could please tell me if asking about checking emails and other text in foreign languages is normal on this site or maybe should I go somewhere else, maybe some subreddit or something?

Comment: Although InBedded16 has answered your question, proof-reading / script correction is not a service offered on this site. A more experienced responder would have pointed this out to you. The site deals with questions of grammar, idiom and expression, not the quality of someone's prose.

Comment: @KnowledgeEnthusiast, "[Grammarly can *help*!](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/grammarly-grammar-checker/kbfnbcaeplbcioakkpcpgfkobkghlhen?hl=en)". You can try it if you're in a hurry or don't have enough time to read through and check again what you've written. But, it's just an AI-powered tool, so you can expect it to show some stupid/wrong suggestions. It happens when it doesn't recognize a phrase (sometimes, even commonly used ones) or something similar. So, don't always depend on it.

Comment: @RonaldSole oop sorry. I am not a frequenter of this site and didn't realize. I will say that the rules of ELL do not specify that asking for proofreading is off topic or anything of the sort, so not sure how OP or I was supposed to know that.

Comment: @InBedded No harm done. Take the tour to get a better idea of what's offered.